# Using Regex to delete all text except matching string

Tags: regex, notepad++

I know this has been covered by other posts (I think I've read them all), but I just can't figure out this simple problem. In Notepad++ I want to delete all text from a html file except a number of strings. In this example text:

```
text text <text> "text"
text text text 
<div class="cit-form-select"><input value="spamr;1/2/99" />
text text text 
<div class="cit-form-select"><input value="spamr;1/5/128" />
```

I want to delete everything except the data between spamr; and the subsequent quote, with line breaks between the matches. The end result would look like this:

```
1/2/99
1/5/128
```

How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following regex:

```
^[\s\S]*?\bspamr;([^"]+).*
```

And replace with `$1`. This will also remove empty lines, but keeps the remainder of the text. The pattern that removes all text including the remaining one at the end is a bit less efficient:

```
^(?![\s\S]*?spamr;)[\s\S]*\z|^[\s\S]*?\bspamr;([^"]+).*
```

**Regex 1**: The `^` makes the regex look for the string at the beginning of the line, `[\s\S]*?` will match any characters including a  newline as few times as possible (ensuring the closest rightmost match), then `\b` ensures we match whole word `spamr` with the trailing `;`, then we capture 1 or more characters other than a quote with `[^"]+`, and finally match the rest of the line with `.*`.

**Regex 2**: `^(?![\s\S]*?spamr;)[\s\S]*\z` is an alternative added to remove the text after the last occurrence of `spamr;`. It matches any number of any characters before the very end of text (`\z`), that does not contain `spamr;` (achieved with the anchored at the start of the line negative look-ahead `(?![\s\S]*?spamr;)`).

[image]

Comment: This works, thanks! The only thing it doesn't do yet is delete the text after the last occurence of the matched string. Any addition that could get rid of that as well?

Comment: Try `(?:(?!spamr;)[\s\S])*\z|^[\s\S]*?\bspamr;([^"]+).*`. Or looks like this one also works: `^(?![\s\S]*?spamr;)[\s\S]*\z|^[\s\S]*?\bspamr;([^"]+).*`.

Answer (score 1):

Find What: `.*spamr;(.*)".*|.*`

Replace with: `\1`

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.